# Dropwizard - Resumeable file upload

Tags: java, dropwizard

Can someone let me know how can we implement a resumeable file upload in dropwizard 1.2.6? So if a user is trying to upload a large file (4-5 GB) and if there is a network failure or the browser is closed by mistake then the user will be able to resume the process from where it was interrupted.

Comment: This is a question that is more about the HTTP implementation than about Dropwizard. HTTP knows [100 Continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/100) and the [Expect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect) header. But I am not aware that Jersey (JAX-RS implementation used by Dropwizard) implements them. Perhaps take a look at https://tus.io/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tus.io](https://tus.io/) can be used with dropwizard to support resumable upload. An working example is placed in the below github repo

https://github.com/tomdesair/tus-java-server-dropwizard-demo